Legal restrictions on shortcuts, hotkeys, or keybindings
vim keybindings are very popular among programmers, and used across many tools. Vim happens to be open source, so anyone can use the keybindings. However, for a new tool, would it be possible to copyright/trademark/patent, or apply other IP restrictions to the shortcuts, so other people can't use them?

I'm not sure why the downvotes. I phrased it in terms of creating restrictions on a new invention, but it is really also about determining whether it is possible for existing inventions to have IP restrictions. I get the sense people downvoted because it seems like a scummy question to restrict shortcuts, but I'm not considering doing this.


copyright/trademark/patent...

Copyright
Is a keystroke or combination of keys origibal or artistic in any way and not functional? No, it is all functional, it can't be copyrighted.
Trademark
Can a combination of keystrokes be a mark of origin of a good or product? No. So it can't be trademarked.
Patent
The idea of combining specific keys to get a machine to do something is not novel. As such, it is not a novel or non-obvious thing: the Shift Key is as old as the typewriter to swap between two character sets and there have been typewriters with levers to swap to a totally different font. So the idea of "combining two keys to make something happen different" is not novel and obvious prior art. Having just "I press Ctrl+P for pause on any layer of the PC" is not patentable: you use already implemented, System side control code as input, it's business standard, no patentability.
All patents for keybinds I find are for methods to find them or modified keyboards that do pre-processing.
There's KR101648326B1, a 2016 patent on a modification of a keyboard. The novel thing here was not the idea of combining two keys, but to input non-standard characters by combining a set of reduced-characters resulting in most characters taking at least 2 button presses unlike standard methods like pressing shift. That's not obvious and the actual patented part is the "special key" that turns on the module inside the keyboard that turns the input into unicode directly in the keyboard.
There's CN101228500A, again a patent for a modified keyboard. As far as I understand the bad translation it does some evaluating of keystrokes in the keyboard and sends the resulting alternate signal instead of having the computer solve it. That again, is probably not an obvious solution to a problem.

Microsoft did use trademark rights in their Windows key combinations. This forced computer and keyboard manufacturers to sign licensing agreements, or else they'd have to use a confusing alternate symbol (penguin, meta/diamond). The specification for keyboard shortcuts can also be copyrighted, this would force implementers to pay for or license the spec, or reverse engineer the scheme.

Windows is because ethe key carries the branding, and has nothing to do with the code. The Spec is the text explaining how to do stuff, that is different from the code that does stuff (also a copyright) but neither is the shortcut itself
